# PHP, implicit_flush: enable to run two instances of the same script in the same browser

Tags: php, browser, flush, autoflush

I have a PHP script that uses implicit_flush() to output data when it's ready, the problem is that when I start two instances from Google chrome or Firefox the seconde instance remains loading without outputing anything!

To prevent locking issues with session files, I have turned Off `session.auto_start` in the php.ini file, and I added a `session_write_close()` at the begining of the script to be sure.

But if run the two instances on two differente browsers, the two work perfectly. If I run the second instance on an incognito mode in Chrome, it doesn't work.

Is the problem relative to the browser, the server, or router? Is there any solution to bypass this restriction?

Edit: because two instances run on two browser I think the only possibility is a browser problem.